# Trying to convert enum to custom string name with JsonStringEnumConverter

Tags: c#, json, enums

I was trying represent some use-case scenario like below. I have json formatted data. And it include an enum class. They send this enum class with int type. I want to show this enum value with a meaningful string. But I couldn't make it.

How can I show this EnumMember custom value?

Edit: I want to show "Not Hot" value. Not Hot_Not enum.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var jsonString = "{\"Summary\":\"40\"}";
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions {
        Converters = {
            new JsonStringEnumConverter()
        }
    };
    WeatherForecastWithEnum ? weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize < WeatherForecastWithEnum > (jsonString, options) !;
    Console.WriteLine(weatherForecast.Summary);
}

public class WeatherForecastWithEnum {
    public Summary ? Summary {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public enum Summary {
    Cold = 30,
    Cool = 10,
    Warm = 20,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Not Hot")]
    Hot_Not = 40
}
```

Comment: The code you have here is deserialising, and is doing that correctly. Where exactly do you want to show the EnumMember value?

Comment: I'm guessing you want the value of `WeatherForecastWithEnum` to be `"Not Hot"` and not `"Not_Hot"`.  It's not that surprising that `EnumMemberAttribute` doesn't work, it's from `System.Runtime.Serialization`.  You probably need to write a custom JSON converter (factory-based, probably).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to.  They aren't that hard, but, if I remember correctly, there are some gotchas.  By the way, you might consider the System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute instead of `EnumMember` - maybe

Comment: Like @Flydog57 said, I want to show `"Not Hot"` string in the deserialized object. I tried `DescriptionAttribute` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it is not supported with `System.Text.Json` . You can see the request for the same.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31081

But there is an extension library called 'Macross.Json.Extensions' where you can use `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` attribute and then do what you need.

```
JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
public enum DefinitionType
{
   [EnumMember(Value = "UNKNOWN_DEFINITION_000")]
   DefinitionUnknown
}

     [TestMethod]
    public void ExampleTest()
    {
        string Json =  JonSerializer.Serialize(DefinitionType.DefinitionUnknown);

        Assert.AreEqual("\"UNKNOWN_DEFINITION_000\"", Json);

        DefinitionType ParsedDefinitionType =    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DefinitionType>(Json);

         Assert.AreEqual(DefinitionType.DefinitionUnknown, ParsedDefinitionType);
   }
```

You can see more at - https://github.com/Macross-Software/core/tree/develop/ClassLibraries/Macross.Json.Extensions#enumerations